# Python Dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch

I am attempting to create a model, I have a sample of images and labels, and in my attempt at loading the two as a custom dataset to the dataloader, I keep encountering a type error:

> 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Here's the code:

```
train_data = vids_and_label(training_data_set, vid_cvs_labels, sequence_length=10, transform=train_transfrom)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)


class vids_and_label(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, vid_title, labels, sequence_length=60, transform=None):
        self.label = labels
        self.video_title = vid_title
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.video_title

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        path = self.video_title[item]
        _vid = f'{path}'.split('\\')[-1]
        _lbls = self.label
        frames = []
        _label = _lbls.iloc[(_lbls.loc[_lbls['file'] == _vid].index.values[0]), 1]
        if _label == 'fake' or _label == 'FAKE':
            _label = 0
        if _label == 'real' or _label == 'REAL':
            _label = 1

        for i, _frame in enumerate(frame_slicer(path)):
            frames.append(self.transform(_frame))
            if len(frames) == self.sequence_length:
                break
        frames = torch.stack(frames)
        frames = frames[:self.sequence_length]
        return frames, _label
```

Comment: Which list was trying to be interpreted as an integer?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if error shows you which line makes problem then you first you could use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`) to check what you have in variables.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - i.e `Dataset`, `DataLoader`, and `VidsAndLabel` - because it helps to recognize class in code. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)